# Add aggregate count in column (javascript) grouping header template

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to include a count for the total rows in a grouping in my grouping header, just like the `count` in this demo: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/aggregates

I'm using a javascript function as the `ClientGroupHeaderTemplate`:

```
columns.Bound(r => r.Status).Title("Status").ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("#= templateFunction(data, statusDisplayArray) #")
```

And the js function:

```
function templateFunction(data, statusDisplayArray){
    var count = 0; // total grouped items goes here
    return "Status: " + statusDisplayArray.lookup[data.value][0].displayString + " (" + count + ")";
}
```

I'm noticing on my `data` argument there is an `aggregates` object available, but I'm not sure how to use this to show an aggregate count. I've seen others use an inline template to get the count, but I need a javascript function as the template to allow for some data conversion. How can I achieve an aggregate count in the javascript function for my `ClientGroupHeaderTemplate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by using the following property:

`data.aggregates.parent().items.length`

Comment: can you pls show your demo. am facing similar issue. in my kendo gird, it has loaded with default column group. if add one more column it shows wrong count value in default column group